# Why is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx^{2})}{1+n^{4}}$ continuously differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $M>0$. In the closed interval $[-M,M]$ we get that:

1. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx^{2})}{1+n^{4}}$ converges at $x_{0}=0$
2. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sin(nx^{2})}{1+n^{4}}\right)'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2nx\cos(nx^{2})}{1+n^{4}}$
   and $\left|\frac{2nx\cos(nx^{2})}{1+n^{4}}\right|\leq\frac{2nM}{1+n^{4}}$.
   Also $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2nM}{1+n^{4}}<\infty$ so
   by the Weierstrass M-test, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sin(nx^{2})}{1+n^{4}}\right)'$
   converges uniformely in $[-M,M]$.

Therefore, by the term by term differentiation theorem there exists a function
$f\colon[-M,M]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx^{2})}{1+n^{4}}$
uniformly and $\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx^{2})}{1+n^{4}}\right)'=f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sin(nx^{2})}{1+n^{4}}\right)'$.

Finally, $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{\sin(nx^{2})}{1+n^{4}}\right)'$
is continuous in $[-M,M]$ for every $N$, then by the uniform convergence  $f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sin(nx^{2})}{1+n^{4}}\right)'$
is also continuous in $[-M,M]$.

My question is how can i generalize this argument to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $\Bbb R$ is covered by the interiors of the $[-M,M]$

Comment: You just need to show that your sum is uniform convergent for all $x \in (a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Doesn't $x^{n}$ converge uniformly to $0$ in $[0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$
for every $n$, but still doesn't converge unifomly to $0$ on $[0,1)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$
?

Comment: @Jon Yes, and didn't you ask about continuous differentiability and not uniform convergence?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown True, but i still can't see how this property passes on to the union of these closed sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently what i was missing is this:

Let $x_{0}\in\mathbb{R}$ ,

We need to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx^{2})}{1+n^{4}}$
is continuously differentiable at $x_{0}$. That is to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx^{2})}{1+n^{4}}$
is differentiable at $x_{0}$ and that $\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx^{2})}{1+n^{4}}\right)'$
is continuous at $x_{0}$.

Choose $M=\left|x_{0}\right|+1$ so $x_{0}\in[-M,M]$ and
from the argument above we get what we need.